# I want disable the delete button when count =1 and I want to enable the delete button when count equals to 0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">PRODUCT_NAME</th>
                <th scope="col">PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION</th>
                <th scope="col">PRODUCT_IMAGE</th>
                <th scope="col">PRODUCT_CODE</th>
                <th scope="col">CATEGORY_NAME</th>
                <th scope="col">OPERATION</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> @foreach ($products as $product ) <tr>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->id}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->Product_name}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->Product_description}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->Product_image}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->Product_code}}</td>
                <td scope="col">{{ $product->Category_id}}</td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <form action="{{route('store.product.destroy',$product->id)}}" method="POST"
                        onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete it')"> <a class="btn btn-info"
                            href="{{route('store.product.edit',$product->id)}}">EDIT</a> <a class="btn btn-warning"
                            href="{{ route('store.product.show',$product->id)}}">SHOW</a> @csrf @method('DELETE') <button
                            type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">DELETE</button> </form>
                </td>
            </tr> @endforeach </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="{{route('store.product.create')}}" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button> </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

This is my controller page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        $data=array( 'products' =>Product::all() );
        return view('product.index',$data);
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource. *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        $category=array( 'category' =>Category::all() );
        return view('home',$category);
    }
    
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $req) {
        $product =new Product();
        $product->Product_name=$req->input('Product_name');
        $product->Product_description= $req->input('Product_description');
        $product->Product_image= $req->file('Product_image')->store('Product_image');
        $product->Product_code= $req->input('Product_code');
        $product->Category_id= $req->input('Category_id');
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('store.product.index',['products'=>$product->id]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id) {
        $category=array( 'category' =>Category::all() );
        return view('product.show',$category, ['product' => Product::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        $category=array( 'category' =>Category::all() );
        return view('product.edit',$category, ['product'=>Product::FindOrFail($id)]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request) {
        $product=Product::find($request->id);
        $product->Product_name=$request->input('Product_name');
        $product->Product_description= $request->input('Product_description');
        $product->Product_image= $request->input('Product_image','public');
        $product->Product_code= $request->input('Product_code');
        $product->Category_id= $request->input('Category_id');
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('store.product.index', ['product'=> $product->id]);
    }
    
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->delete();
        echo ("User Record deleted successfully.");
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has no `count` mentioned anyway. Which count do you mean?

Comment: Where is the category_id count you wrote about in the code? What is keeping you from disabling the button if you have that count somewhere? This site is more about finding errors and receive programming tips and debugging help... it is not a place where people write all the code for you.